# Selenium_Unable to click on 'continue with google' link on Gaana webpage

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[Screenshot of webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81hy8.png)
Already tried with locator By.ID and switch to alert, switch to windows..  but no luck
Please help

```
public class Gaana {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Music\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");  
            ChromeOptions ops = new ChromeOptions();
            ops.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(ops);
            driver.get("https://gaana.com/");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            WebElement googleLgn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Continue with Google')]"));        
            googleLgn.click();
        }               

    }
```

Comment: this error I am getting:

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

Comment: What is the line the exception occurs in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is is 2 login button with same `Id` and same `class` name. Try with below xpath to locate correct button.

```
WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
WebElement element1 = wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("(//a[@id='google-login'])[1]")));
element1.click();
```

**OR**

Try with JS

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@id='google-login'])[1]"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
```

Comment: Still getting the same error with Xpath @Muzzamil
WebElement googleLgn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[@id='google-login'])[1]"));

Comment: @preetD  Please try updated solution.

Comment: Try with second solution with Js if first will not work. Second one should work

Comment: Perfect. Which solution is worked for you?